# React MUI Dropdown menu in side persistent Drawer not showing item list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I integrated a React MUI dropdown select menu in a persistent Side Drawer, but I encountered an issue where I couldn't see the menu list when attempting to select an option while the Drawer was open. However, when I closed the Drawer, the menu list appeared behind it.

[Here is the sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/demodrawer-forked-j1czzq?file=/Drawer.jsx:974-984)

Steps to reproduce

1. Click the menu button
2. Try to open the dropdown menu inside the drawer
3. Close the drawer

Comment: Shot in the dark but have you tried adjusting the z-index of the menu items?

Comment: Yes, I tried to change the z-index.

Comment: Your `zIndex: 2200` on `.MuiDrawer-paper` is blowing *way* past the `Select`'s `Popover`. I can't determine from your code *why* you have that `zIndex` in there, but removing/lowering it fixes your issue.